# Google Script: Append new values in column to another sheet

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been working on this project and can't get it to work quite the way I want.

I have two sheets with unique IDs in one column. I need to make sure whenever a new ID is added in one sheet (Sheet1), it is copied to the last empty row in the other sheet (Sheet2). Making sure it ignores it if the value already exist (to avoid duplicates). The idea was to create a function and have it triggered every minute or so.

Below is the example spreadsheet and the script that is almost working now. The only issue is that instead of adding new values to the first empty row at the bottom, is copying them in a weird order (see Sheet2 to see what I mean). The header in my spreadsheet is in row 4, and I'm guessing the issue has something to do with that?

Example Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Ty5pWhLULDn6GZ1Qb3RqR556TXjIL7GdWvxW2xJ7M0/edit?usp=sharing

Script:

```
function updateSheet() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = "Sheet1"; 
var destinationSheet = "Sheet2";
var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
var lastCol = target_sheet.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = target_sheet.getLastRow();

//assumes headers in row 1
var r = target_sheet.getRange(2,1, lastRow - 1, lastCol);

//Note the use of an array
r.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);

  // Process sheet
  _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet);

}


function _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet) {
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();  
  var source_data = source_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var target_data = target_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];
  
  for (var n = 1 ; n < source_data.length ; n++) {
    var keep = true;
      for(var p in target_data) {
       if (source_data[n][0] == target_data[p][0]) {
                 keep = false; break;
      }
    }
    Logger.log(keep);
 //   if(keep){ resultArray.push(source_data[n])};
//    if(keep){ resultArray.push([source_data[n][0]])};
    var columnsToKeep = [0];
    var tempData = [];
    if(keep){
      for(var c in columnsToKeep){ tempData.push(source_data[n][columnsToKeep[c]])}
    resultArray.push(tempData);
    }     
  }
  last_row++;
  Logger.log(resultArray);
  if(resultArray.length>0){
    target_sheet.getRange(last_row,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: How does data get added to you spreadsheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to append unique values from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2" after it sorts the cells "A2:A" on "Sheet2" by modifying your script.

For this, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your case, how about retrieving the cells "A4:A" from `source_sheet` instead of `getDataRange()`?
- In your script, when no values in "Sheet2", an error occurs at `target_sheet.getRange(2,1, lastRow - 1, lastCol)`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function updateSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = "Sheet1"; 
  var destinationSheet = "Sheet2";
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
  var lastCol = target_sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow > 1) { // <--- Added
    var r = target_sheet.getRange(2,1, lastRow - 1, lastCol);
    r.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);
  }
  _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet);
}

function _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet) {
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();  
  var source_data = source_sheet.getRange("A4:A" + source_sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); // <--- Modified
  var target_data = target_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];
  for (var n = 0 ; n < source_data.length ; n++) { // <--- Modified
    var keep = true;
      for(var p in target_data) {
       if (source_data[n][0] == target_data[p][0]) {
         keep = false; break;
       }
    }
    var columnsToKeep = [0];
    var tempData = [];
    if(keep){
      for(var c in columnsToKeep){ tempData.push(source_data[n][columnsToKeep[c]])}
      resultArray.push(tempData);
    }     
  }
  last_row++;
  resultArray = resultArray.filter(String);  // <--- Added
  if(resultArray.length>0){
    target_sheet.getRange(last_row,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
  }
}
```

- By this modification, when "Sheet2" has no values, the header `ID` is put to the 1st row. After 2nd run, 1st row is ignored and the cells below 2nd row are sorted, and then, the new unique value is appended.

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Comment: This is great @tanaike ! Thanks so much for reviewing. I made the changes in the [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Ty5pWhLULDn6GZ1Qb3RqR556TXjIL7GdWvxW2xJ7M0/edit#gid=198196905). But there's this weird behaviour when an ID is added in lower cells in Sheet1 (id B23 as an example), the script is placing that in a random cell in Sheet2. Do you know why does this happen? The original intention was to be able to append any new ID that doesn't exist (avoiding duplicates) in Sheet2, at the bottom of Sheet2 in the first empty cel.

Comment: @Mel Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I updated the modified script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: awesome!! it works perfectly, exactly what I need. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Mel Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: follow up question if is not too much trouble :) How can I edit the script so it inserts the IDs in the target sheet after row 10 for example? So basically make it ignore the rows 1 to 10 in the target sheet, since there is other info in my original file that I don't want to change. Thanks in advance for the help in any case!

Comment: the idea is to be able to target the range in the target sheet, where the IDs are inserted. Thanks!

Comment: @Mel I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. And unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I added a new question here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935702/google-script-copy-values-from-one-sheet-to-another-determining-the-range

Comment: @Mel Thank you for your response. I saw it just now. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. And I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: the answer I got is not solving my problem. Would be great if you were able to contribute :) I'm sure the modifications will be issuer as you created part of the script. Thanks in any case.

Comment: @Mel Thank you for replying. When I saw it now, I noticed that the answerer commented your replying. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussions. I believe that the answerer will resolve your issue.