# Google Script: copy values from one sheet to another determining the range

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets with unique IDs in one column. I need to make sure whenever a new ID is added in one sheet (Sheet1), it is copied to the last empty row in the other sheet (Sheet2). The IMPORTRANGE won't work as being dynamic any static information added in the other sheet would be irrelevant to the respective ID.

In another thread [1], I got help developing this script that will do exactly that. However, this script will insert the data in the other sheet in Column A. How can I modify the script so I can decide the specific range where I want the script to insert the data (in Sheet 2).

Update: I created this spreadsheet as an example. I'm trying to ensure that the script does the calculation (ie. adding vlaues that are not duplicated in the first available empty row), starting in cel C10 in "Sheet2". It would be also great if I can somehow change that range if I need to: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1abESAXFrOHoqRQRNqQGfmAFxlbD10wlprAf1tca4y7o/edit#gid=132361488

Thanks!

```js
function updateSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = "Sheet1"; 
  var destinationSheet = "Sheet2";
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
  var lastCol = target_sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow > 1) { // <--- Added
    var r = target_sheet.getRange(2,1, lastRow - 1, lastCol);
    r.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);
  }
  _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet);
}

function _updateSpreadsheet(source_sheet, target_sheet) {
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();  
  var source_data = source_sheet.getRange("A4:A" + source_sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); // <--- Modified
  var target_data = target_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];
  for (var n = 0 ; n < source_data.length ; n++) { // <--- Modified
    var keep = true;
      for(var p in target_data) {
       if (source_data[n][0] == target_data[p][0]) {
         keep = false; break;
       }
    }
    var columnsToKeep = [0];
    var tempData = [];
    if(keep){
      for(var c in columnsToKeep){ tempData.push(source_data[n][columnsToKeep[c]])}
      resultArray.push(tempData);
    }     
  }
  last_row++;
  resultArray = resultArray.filter(String);  // <--- Added
  if(resultArray.length>0){
    target_sheet.getRange(last_row,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
  }
}
```

[1] [Google Script: Append new values in column to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62686052/google-script-append-new-values-in-column-to-another-sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
target_sheet.getRange(last_row,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length)
.setValues(resultArray);
```

This line

- Takes the sheet stored in the variable `target_sheet`
- Accesses the defined range
- Sets values

The syntax to access a range used in your code is [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

whereby the start column is numerical - in your case it's `1` which corresponds to column `A`.

**If you want to modify the start column from `A` to `B`:**

Just change your range definition from

`getRange(last_row,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length)`

to

`getRange(last_row,2,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ziganotschka! Following the syntax I was guessing I can change "last_row" to determine the row where I need to insert the data, but is giving me very weird results. How can I modify the script so I can specify a specific range where to insert the data (e.g. C10:C)? So something similar to where I specify the range to retrieve the data in the other sheet "source_sheet.getRange("A4:A" + source_sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();" where it will pull the range "A4:A". Thanks!

Comment: I created this spreadsheet as an example. I'm trying to ensure that the script does the calculation (ie. adding vlaues that are not duplicated in the first available empty row), starting in cel C10 in "Sheet2". It would be also great if I can somehow change that range if I need to: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1abESAXFrOHoqRQRNqQGfmAFxlbD10wlprAf1tca4y7o/edit#gid=132361488

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to insert data starting with the first empty row - it should be `last_row+1` instead of `last_row`. For the method `setValues()` you cannot define `C10:C)` because you need to make sure that the number of rows corresponds correctly to the one in your value range - that is `resultArray.length`. So you need to specify for starting with `C10`:`target_sheet.getRange(10,3,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length)` or `target_sheet.getRange("C10:C" + (10+resultArray.length))`.

Comment: Alternatively use the method [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) for which you only need to specify the first cell of the destination range.

Comment: thanks @ziganotschka. I tested in the example sheet I linked but nothing is happening. Just to be clear, the current script will do exactly what I want but always in column A, starting in row 1. So it will see if values from source sheet exist and if not append any new value in the first empty row in column A. I still want this to be the behavior, but be able to determine the column and row where the script should do this operation in the target sheet. Using both of your alternatives is not doing anything. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but now I'm blocked

Comment: I see that I did not explain myself well: Aftere retrieving the updated range (so column 3 instead of column 1) - you still need to use the method `setValues(resultArray); ` - otherwise how is your function supposed to know that it shall set the values into the range? So: `target_sheet.getRange(10,3,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray); `

Comment: I recommend you to invest some time to go through the [.as tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials) to get a better feeling for what the code dies and how to dapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the input @ziganotschka. Your solution definitely works in an empty sheet. But when using the sheet that already has some data in other columns, the script messes up the cells, changing their order, in a very weird way. My guess is that the script is somehow impacting all the columns. I definitely have to learn more and will study the tutorials you shared. thanks